# deploy django apps using CherryPy

Tags: django, deployment, cherrypy

I want to deploy my django application using CherryPy. But I am looking for a pluggable apps instead of a scripts (which I'll just deploy it via apache)

Any good django apps that do that?

Thanks,
James

Answer (score 2):

[django-cpserver](http://lincolnloop.com/blog/2008/mar/25/serving-django-cherrypy/)